# Why will_paginate not loaded in rails 3.2.8 engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

Here is the code in our index to return @customers:

```
@customers = Customerx::Customer.where(:active => true).order("since_date DESC, id DESC").paginate(:per_page => 30, :page => params[:page])
```

It causes error of below:

```
undefined method `paginate' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x6b88960>
```

In debug, `ActiveRecord::Base.respond_to? :paginate` returns `false`. It seems to us that the will_paginate was not loaded, even though `will_paginate (3.0.3)`  was returned with `gem list`.

What could be wrong with the code?

Comment: You're definitely going to want to upgrade Rails to 3.2.11, because of some vulnerabilities that were recently found. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rubyonrails-security/61bkgvnSGTQ

Comment: Thanks for the info. A friend has told us about the security issue. The program is still in development.

Comment: I don't mean to be a pest about it, but you should upgrade *any* Rails app to the latest 3.2.11, 3.1.10, 3.0.19 and 2.3.15 releases - even if they're not deployed anywhere. The same vulnerabilities that make your server vulnerable to attack are currently making your local dev machine(s) vulnerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was fixed by adding `gem will_paginate` in engine's gemfile, even though `gem will_paginate` is in gemspec for the rails engine. The problem was caused by gem paginate was not loaded as `ActiveRecord::Base.respond_to? :paginate` returned false.

Here is a post that is somewhat similar to the problem here.

[Rails Engine - Gems dependencies, how to load them into the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159607/rails-engine-gems-dependencies-how-to-load-them-into-the-application)

Answer (score 1):

even I used to get this error, so I tried page method...use

```
@customers = Customerx::Customer.where(:active => true).order("since_date DESC, id DESC").page(params[:page]).per_page(30)
```