# why does RSpec fail with undefined method [] Nil::NilClass for AWS_CONFIG['bucket']

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-engines

config/initializers/aws_config.rb:

```
AWS_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/aws.yml")[Rails.env]
```

Model has code:

```
self.bucket = AWS_CONFIG["bucket"]
```

Test result:

```
 Failure/Error: self.bucket = AWS_CONFIG['bucket']
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

There's no problem in development or production running the code, why does the aws_config initializer fail under RSpec?

Comment: When you open your `rails console` what does the AWS_CONFIG give you? My guess is that the `test` key is not set/properly in the config file. kindly confirm this!

Comment: Can you paste your aws.yml file just hide the was credentials

Comment: rails console works fine, AWS_CONFIG['bucket'] is setup with the correct value. I will add that this is a rails engine I'm testing. The aws.yml file is basically what is posted in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the 'test' is not set/properly in your configuration file.
As an added bonus, when loading your configuration files from config/*.yml, Rails provides a helper method to fetch the configurations.
Assuming you've nested your configurations appropriately, you should be able to `#{your app name here(find it in config/application.rb)}::Application.config_for(:aws)`, if you've set it properly, you should just be able to fetch the values, without looking under the environment.

Take a look at this for example

```
production:
  secret_key: 000894jnjfbdfu39
  secret_id: 123456
  bucket: shadow

development:
  secret_key: 000894jnjfbdfu39
  secret_id: 123456
  bucket: shadow

test:
  secret_key: 000894jnjfbdfu39
  secret_id: 123456
  bucket: meadow
```

In your application initializer, you could then have:

`AWS_CONFIG = YourApp::Application.config_for(:aws)`
All other things should work normally after this.

Answer (score 0):

engine.rb did not require gems.

this is why model didn't have AWS_CONFIG, while rails console did.

See, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24768678/6442724), for how to load gems in engine.