# How to use engine's gem in main application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am making a rails plugin named `signup`.
In this plugin, I used `bcrypt` gem, Here is my engine.rb

```
module Signup
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Signup   

    require 'rubygems'
    require 'bcrypt'

  end
end
```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'    
gemspec    
gem 'bcrypt'
```

I follow this [Rails Engine - Gems dependencies, how to load them into the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159607/rails-engine-gems-dependencies-how-to-load-them-into-the-application)

But In my demo application, when start rails server, then I got this error:

```
lib/signup/engine.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt (LoadError)
```

I want to load `bcrypt` gem in my demo application. If I add `gem 'bcrypt'` in my demo application's Gemfile and run bundle install, it does not show any kind of error, But I don't want to do it.

I want that `gem 'bcrypt'` will be load automatically in my demo application without adding this in Gemfile.

Comment: specify bcrypt as dependency in your gemspec not in gemfile

Comment: @ArkadiuszOleksy I did it, but not worked. Also shows this error while I am going to bundle install

```
Your Gemfile lists the gem bcrypt (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
```

Comment: Did you use `bundle install` after specifying it in your gemspec?

Comment: yes,but not work.