# Forcing gem dependencies on host rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an engine gem that uses slim templates within it's views. I also have a host rails application that uses erb templates and doesn't have slim rails in it's gemfile.

I'm trying to force the dependency of slim through the gem. It seems that you can render slim files into an erb file, although this is generally bad practice. As it stands, when:

```
add_dependency "slim-rails"
```

is added into the gemspec, it bundles slim-rails from the host app but I still get an error that it can't find the template because it's not looking for slim in the file types. In the end i've had to add 'slim-rails' to the host app, but the ideal solution would be for the dependency to work correctly.

Am i doing something wrong? The gem is currently implemented as a submodule that sits in the directory but the path is set correctly etc.

Comment: Tried any of those: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24768678/906511 ?

Comment: The solution on that post worked for me, thanks for the reference! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Engine - Gems dependencies, how to load them into the application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159607/rails-engine-gems-dependencies-how-to-load-them-into-the-application)

Comment: You're welcome. I will mark this as a duplicate then.