# Rails plugin/engine can not load paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am developing a rails plugin. I have paperclip in the gemspec file:

```
spec.add_dependency 'paperclip', '~> 5.1'
```

After installing gems (using `bundle install`), it shows that the paperclip gem is installed in the plugin.

After adding `has_attached_file` in `app/models/my_plugin/class_with_data_file_entity`:

```
class ClassWithDataFileEntity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :file, url: "/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:filename",
end
```

I see the following error:

```
undefined method `has_attached_file' for #<Class:0x0000000354e7e8>
```

So, the plugin can not find paperclip. Why would that be? Can Paperclip be used in a rails plugin

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer - [Rails Engine - Gems dependencies, how to load them into the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159607/rails-engine-gems-dependencies-how-to-load-them-into-the-application/24768678#24768678)

you have to require 'paperclip' in your engine.rb