# Rails 5 Engine - Gems dependencies, how to load them into the application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-engines

I'm having the same issue as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159607/rails-engine-gems-dependencies-how-to-load-them-into-the-application) but none of the solutions here are working. A couple hours of searching and of course reading the main [Rails Engine docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) have all turned up the same strategies as the SO link. I'm wondering if there is something different about the way Rails 5 handles dependencies.

I have this dependency in my gemspec:

`s.add_development_dependency "pg_search"`

I have this line in my engine.rb file:

```
require "pg_search"
```

When I run rails s from within the engine's directory, everything loads fine. When I mount the engine and try to start the server from the rails app directory, I get this error:

```
/home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': cannot load such file -- pg_search (LoadError).
```

Finally, if I add the pg_search gem to the Gemfile of the app that is mounting the engine, the rails server starts. This of course isn't a solution, I'm just trying to provide complete information.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because I used 'add_development_dependency' rather than 'add_dependency'.